# Unable to resolve module (Expo, React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo

Building a React Native app with Expo, the Javascript bundle fails after getting the error `Unable to resolve "../stores/__fixtures__/matchlist/matchlistSourceFixture" from "src/containers/MatchlistSwipeContainer.tsx"`, despite the fact that I am 100% sure this file exists and its relative path in this instance is correct – especially as I’m using VSCode and it complains if the path isn’t right and I’m using VSCode’s autocomplete to begin with.

If I move the file into any other directory that is not with __ dunder affixes and update the relative path accordingly, it can find the file perfectly fine.

I’ve checked other similar topics with Unable to resolve module errors, but they all seem to be related to third-party packages, whereas this is a local file.

Import statement:

`import { matchlistSourceFixture } from '../stores/__fixtures__/matchlist/matchlistSourceFixture';`

Export statement in the file in `matchlistSourceFixture.ts`:

`export const matchlistSourceFixture = {...}`

Attached is an image of the error message in the Expo iOS app. The message stating that the file doesn’t even exist (it has a .ts extension by the way) makes me think the relative path isn’t really the issue here anyway.

[image: Screenshot of 'unable to resolve module' error on Expo iOS app]

Versions:

- React 16.3.1
- Expo 27.0.0
- Exp 54.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `__fixtures__` dirs are blacklisted by default in RN: [react-native/local-cli/util/Config.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9176fc00b59d1a384008f26d72ba57a2a08e0726/local-cli/util/Config.js#L55-L57).

[See this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17610#issuecomment-357884014) on overriding the default.

Comment: How bizarre. Why would they blacklist that? And it looks like that's the only blacklisted directory name...

Comment: Yes, it's odd. Especially annyoing for me as __fixtures__ is a convention in React Cosmos.

Comment: I couldn't find any info on *why* they blacklist it. Do you know what the reason might be?

Comment: No idea. But if you want to dig this is the commit and related issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/54dc11a5fbafaccc9c0a781f1151225909717597 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17610